# detect unused files/folders in a server via apache log

Tags: apache, log-analysis

I inherited a server on which a large number of applications and files are installed.
Many of these are no longer in use, but I have no documentation of what is in production and what is not.
I should try to clean up and remove unused files and applications.
Since I have Apache logs, can I process them with an analyzer or some script to identify the files (or rather the folders) that are no longer in use (which have not had hits since January 2020 for example)?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved it by simply using the grep command.
I used the Apache logs from January to now, and for each folder on the server I launched a command like:

```
cat access_log_20200* |grep "GET /folder"
```

So I deleted the ones that are not present in the log file.